# jQuery fullCalendar - calendar not showing on load in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working with [jQuery fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to show a calendar. I'm also working with [jQuery tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to have multiple tabs.

I want to show the callendar in the first tab. This is what I have in my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reservatiestabs").tabs();

    if($('#calendar').length) {
        var dbEvents = <?php echo $events; ?>;
        var calEvents = getEvents(dbEvents);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next',
            weekends: false,
            defaultView: 'month',
            defaultDate: moment(),
            events: calEvents,
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                displayEvent(calEvent, calendar);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is that my calendar isn't loaded when the page is loaded. The buttons are loaded but not the calendar.

[image]
How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to do this like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#reservatiestabs" ).tabs({ create: function( event, ui ) {
        var dbEvents = <?php echo $events; ?>;
        var calEvents = getEvents(dbEvents);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next',
            weekends: false,
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekNumberCalculation: "ISO",
            defaultView: 'month',
            defaultDate: moment(),
            events: calEvents,
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                displayEvent(calEvent, calendar);
            }
        });
    }});

});
```

But no difference ... .

Comment: Any console errors in browser?

Comment: Try to bind the initialization of calendar when tab's 'create' event is fired:

$( "#reservatiestabs" ).tabs({
  create: function( event, ui ) {
      // init fullcalendar here
  }
});

See http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create for details.

Comment: @Alexey, tried to do it but no difference (updated my topic). No console errors btw.

Comment: Can you please share html fragment with tabset and tab pane for calendar and your <script> tags that include tabs and fullcalendar plugins on jsfiddle.net? `calEvents` could be empty. That would help with debugging.